# MS Azure Storage transactions

Tags: azure, transactions, storage

I'm confused with Storage transactions in Azure Storage for page bolb, so what is mean Storage transactions in Azure Storage.
I want to use to upload all of my website image to their, so I do not know how many transaction i need.

so I i have 1000 photos in my website and every day 1000 gusts visit my website how many Storage transactions required to retrieve from Azure storage to client.

so what about Bandwidth? most of my big file will be in Azure storage only small amount of html and css will be in Azure Web App Storage so I do not know that I need to buy bandwidth or not required since most of load come to Storage transactions.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times - this is all about REST calls. And nothing to do with bandwidth. Plenty of documentation on the Azure site about both transactions and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

The first area we would want to cover for transactions is what equals 1 transaction to Windows Azure Storage. Each and every REST call to Windows Azure Blobs, Tables and Queues counts as 1 transaction (whether that transaction is counted towards billing is determined by the billing classification discussed later in this posting). The REST calls are detailed here:

[Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Blob-Service-REST-API)

[Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Table-Service-REST-API)

[Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Queue-Service-REST-API)

Each one of the above REST calls counts as 1 transaction. This includes the following types of requests:
Query/List Requests and Continuation Tokens – A Table Query, and Listing Blob Containers, Tables and Queues can return continuation tokens. This means that the query/listing must be continued to complete it. As described above, each REST request to the storage service counts as 1 transaction. Therefore, each continuation of the query/list counts as an additional 1 transaction, since it is another REST request to the storage service.

For more information refer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/